# Set-PnPListItem throws Access denied error

Tags: user, pnp-powershell

I am trying to update item in **"User Information List"** using **"Set-PnPListItem"**. but i'm getting following error.

```
Set-PnPListItem : Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

below is my code

```
$ListName = "User Information List"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$PnPContext = Get-PnPContext
$web = $PnPContext.Web 
$PnPContext.Load($web) 
$PnPContext.ExecuteQuery()
Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity 24 -Values @{"Manager"="xxx@domain.onmicrosoft.com" }
```

Note:

**Above code is working fine for other custom lists. only problem with "User Information List".**

**I'm global administrator As well as site collection administrator**

Please help.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Yes but why only for "user info list"? Since i have full control on site collection